# Is that possible to use record name field as master-detail relationship definition in data loader

Tags: data-loader, data-import-wizard

Our customer is previously using import wizard to load data into Salesforce and she is able to use name field as the master-detail relationship field during that time. Due to this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gOnQAI&title=non-unique-external-id-fields-are-incorrectly-available-for-selection-as-matching-criteria-in-the-data-import-wizard . I have suggested her to switch to data loader.

But the issue is the master-detail relationship field no longer matches. It is an id field. Not a text field. So we are getting errors like: Hearing Number: id value of incorrect type: H-718027 .

Is there any walk around for this issue?

Comment: I've always ended up having to do an extract of data from the master table into Excel and use a vlookup to populate the record id field.

Comment: The API supports matching by name, but the data loader does not, as far as I can tell. You might look at a third-party tool, though it might cost you $. For example, I understand that dataloader.io and Relational Junction should both support this feature. The Apex Data Loader simply happens to be a bit too primitive to do useful things like that.